# Como faço para saber o país de um determinado IP?

Tags: php

Bom o que pretendia era saber qual era o país de um determinado IP, eu já usei o geoiplocation do PHP, contudo quando eu meto a rodar no meu servidor aparece-me o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_country_name_by_name() in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\ExtraGrana\new\testando.php on line 4
```

Quando coloco no meu servidor cpanel, aparece a seguinte mensagem: A página "url do meu site" não está a funcionar."

```
<?php


$country = geoip_country_name_by_name('www.google.com');


echo $country;
?>
```

O que estará de errado neste código?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa instalar a extensão PECL para funcionar.
Link: http://php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: A instalação disso em Linux é dificil de se fazer? Não existe nenhuma alternativa mais facil?

Comment: yum install php-pear

Comment: Você pode tentar pegar o IP com JS. Mas se quiser com PHP não conheço outro jeito.

Comment: O IP eu sei pegar, eu queria era o nome do país daquele determinado IP.

Comment: Então. Se você usar o PECL você consegue pegar o nome usando **geoip_country_name_by_name**